# Show text for post with specific date and specific category in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, date, conditional-statements

So I'm trying to show text at the end of each post but from this month only and only in one category. I tried different codes that I found here but none of them really worked or what I needed. Here is example of what I like to do. Hope it make sense.

```
 if(in_category(tags) && date(from June 2015) )
    {
            ?>
        <p>See related news <a href="#">here</a>.</p>
       <p>Subscribe to our monthly e-newsletter <a href="#">here</a>.</p>

  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code . Here I had used category 'Uncategorized' .you can use your tag there.
 hope this will help. add this code in your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'check_cat_date' );

function check_cat_date($content){

      $date    = '2015-06-01';
      $pub_Date =the_date( 'Y-m-d', '' ,'', $echo=false );
      $pub_Date = (string)$pub_Date; 

      $posted_date = strtotime($pub_Date);
      $flag_date   = strtotime($date);


if(in_category('Uncategorized')&&($posted_date) >= $flag_date)
    {


    $append = '<p>See related news <a href="#">here</a>.</p>
            <p>Subscribe to our monthly e-newsletter <a href="#">here</a>.</p>';
    $new_content = $content.$append;

    return $new_content;



    }
    else{
        return $content;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

if i am not wrong by understanding your quest you need to use [`date_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) along with [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'page', // 'post', 'page' or custom post type 'Name' Like `Products`
    'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'category_term', // your taxonomy name
                                'field' => 'slug', // slug or id 
                                'terms' => $catSlug
                            )
                        ),
    'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'year'  => date('Y'), // remove if you dont want
                'month' => date('m'),
                'day'   => date('d'), // remove if you dont want
            ),
        ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

echo '<pre>';print_r($query->posts);echo '</pre>';
```

To check in the Category you should use condition :

get month of every post date and compare it with current month number or hardcode month number like for `June` use `06` you can check for php date formats [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

For `in_category` parameters see [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category)

```
if(in_category('cat_name') && date('m',strtotime($post->post_date)) == date('m'))
{

// your code to view post title 

}
```

Comment: Good answer, but you've misunderstood the question. The OP wants to add a certain text to the post if that particular post is in a specific month with a specific category :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen you are right. Really struggling to get the code right and I tried so many option that now I confused myself.